# PhoneGap how to use dbaq contactsphone plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I wonder how can I use dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers package in my PhoneGap project ? I installed it using

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers.git
```

And I have added contactsPhoneNumbers.js in the js file and referenced it :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contactsPhoneNumbers.js"></script>
```

I have added this code in onDeviceReady function :

```
navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list(function(contacts) {
      alert(contacts.length + ' contacts found');
      for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
         console.log(contacts[i].id + " - " + contacts[i].displayName);
         for(var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
            var phone = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j];
            alert("===> " + phone.type + "  " + phone.number + " (" + phone.normalizedNumber+ ")"); 
         }
      }
   }, function(error) {
      console.error(error);
   });
```

This doesn't work for me. It says that the contactsPhoneNumbers.js file is missing. Please help me out!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would better use the [Cordova Contact Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts).
More stable and easy to use. You can list your contact list and retrieve it as a JSON object.

Comment: here is the issue. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905615/phonegap-retrieve-contacts