# PhoneGap retrieve contacts

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm facing a serious issue while fetching contacts from the contacts list using PhoneGap. I have installed the plugin and did everything but seems it doesn't work for me.

So, What is the problem ?
The problem with it is my contacts having the email accounts.So email doesn't have the phonenumber. 
Here is the screenshot : 
http://prntscr.com/82meyr

```
What is the issue ?
```

Well, the problem is that when it encounters the email the for loop stops immediately and shows the 20-30 contacts only!

```
     function onSuccess(contacts) 
     {
            alert("Total contacts = "+ contacts.length);
            for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) 
            { 
                $('#contactList').append("<li><a href='#'><h2>"+ contacts[i].displayName +"</h2><p>" + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value + "</p></a></li>");  
                 $('#contactList').listview("refresh");
            }
  }
```

---

### My contacts .vcf file. You can import it on your emulator.

---

### Link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43274075/00004.vcf

```
Here is the code I'm using.(already posted but didn't get answer)
```

-->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889859/phonegap-error-on-the-physical-device

```
Is there any way to bypass the email accounts ?
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not check if `contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0] == null` and ignore that contact if so?

Comment: function onSuccess(contacts) 
    {
 
       for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
       {
        if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
        {
         for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) 
         {   
                   $('#contactList').append("<li><a href='#'><h2>"+ contacts[i].displayName +"</h2><p>" + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value + "</p></a></li>");         
                     
                }
        }
    }

Comment: I have done this @Huey but it's duplicating the contact names more time.

Comment: Because it's adding a new entry for each phone number someone with multiple numbers has

Comment: Then what should I do ? @Huey

Comment: function onSuccess(contacts) 
    {
 
        for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
        {
          if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
          {
           for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) 
           {   
                   $('#contactList').append("<li><a href='#'><h2>"+ contacts[i].displayName +"</h2><p>" + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "</p></a></li>");         
                     
             }
          }
        }
  
      
       
     $('#contactList').listview("refresh");
       
    }
Is that true ?